# Can health checks be shared between multiple haproxy instances?

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to somehow share health checks between haproxy sessions? For example if I have 3 haproxy servers as a loadbalancers can you make something like cluster from them?
Now every haproxy server health check every server and it drains a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: Agree with this question. It seems that nothing exist for that...